# encryption with pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I want to encrypt a input line, and this line should be encrypted this way: 
PASSWORD = ABCCDEF , so the first entered letter becomes "A" and that letter stays that way, as you can see, "S" and "S" are both C. Then I want the input line, and the encrypted line to be save to a file (using `pickle`), and the encryption key should be saved, so that we can decrypt it later.

I know how to use pickle, so that part is all good, but the encryption/decryption is fuzzy!

Comment: "I hope I am useing this AskQuestion thingy right" - that's what the [FAQ] is there for.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but why are you using such "encryption" scheme? What's wrong with [AES](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/)?

Comment: Also, your question seems to lack an actual question. And a code excerpt showing what you have so far, and where exactly the problem you're facing lies. (If the problem is "I need someone to implement *$REQUIREMENT* for me", you're in the wrong place.)

Comment: Short of mentioning pickle, this looks like one of several assign a sequential letter/digit to some input type of question

Comment: @kennet, this is a homework assignment or something like that, right? Please don't tell me this is something meant to be used in the real production code.

Comment: @NullUserException, I think it's the algorithm used in several newspaper puzzles as "encrypted text". Every letter gets assigned a number (or a symbol, in this case another letter) in turn: the first gets A, the second occurring letter B and so on. Decryption is usually made with a pencil while waiting for the tube :-). So in a way... it *could be* production code.

Comment: oh no, it is definetly nothing to be used, I am new to python, so nothing as complicated as a to-be-used program!

Comment: The problem! I dont know how to code they "key" if u udnerstand? I can't give u a code example becouse thats pretty much the whole thing, input line, encrypt that line with the encryption key, and "pickle" it to a file..

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, you should probably use a dictionary which maps every char to it's encrypted cipher char. Here's a head start on this. It iterates over every character in `plain`, and append the ciphered char to a new string. Now you just need to think how should the `encryptor` mapping is implemented (hint: Given the number of keys in it, you can assign the next cipher char).

```
plain = 'PASSWORD'
cipher = ''
encryptor = {}

for ch in plain:
    if ch in encryptor:
        # TODO: Implement so that encryptor[ch] = 'A' for the first letter,
        # But encryptor[ch] = 'B' for the second etc
        pass
    cipher += encryptor[ch]
```

Good luck and be sure to write some tests for your code!